# Problemas con Bootstrap y PHP 7

Tags: bootstrap, php7

Estoy haciendo un carrusel interactivo utilizando el framework Bootstrap. Para esto, las imágenes se suben a base de datos y posteriormente son llamadas dentro de las clases que este framework sugiere. El problema es que sí me muestra las imágenes y se pasan solas, pero lo que son los indicadores inferiores y los laterales no funcionan de ninguna forma.

Este es el código:

```
$carrusel=$mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM slider WHERE id_slider!=0 ORDER BY id_slider DESC");

    $cantidad_imagenes=$carrusel->num_rows;

    ?>

    <div class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">

        <ol class="carousel-indicators">

            <?php

            $activo = "active";

            for ($i=0; $i < $cantidad_imagenes; $i++) { 

                ?>

                <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="<?php echo $i; ?>" class="<?php echo $activo; ?>"></li>

                <?php

                $activo = "";

            }

            ?>

        </ol>

        <div class="carousel-inner">

            <?php

            $activo = "active";

            while ($c=mysqli_fetch_array($carrusel)) {

                ?>

                <div class="carousel-item <?php echo $activo; ?>">

                    <img class="d-block w-100" src="imagenes/<?php echo $c['nombre_slider']; ?>">

                </div>

                <?php

                $activo = "";

            }

            ?>

        </div>

        <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="prev">

            <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>

            <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>

        </a>

        <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="next">

            <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>

            <span class="sr-only">Next</span>

        </a>

    </div>
```

Y este es el resultante:

```html
<div class="bd-example">

  <div id="carouselExampleCaptions" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">


    <div class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">

      <ol class="carousel-indicators">


        <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>


        <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="1" class=""></li>


      </ol>

      <div class="carousel-inner">


        <div class="carousel-item active">

          <img class="d-block w-100" src="imagenes/servicios.jpg">

        </div>


        <div class="carousel-item ">

          <img class="d-block w-100" src="imagenes/uno.jpg">

        </div>


      </div>

      <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="prev">

        <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>

        <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>

      </a>

      <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="next">

        <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>

        <span class="sr-only">Next</span>

      </a>

    </div>


  </div>

</div>

</div>
```

Por favor, si alguien pudiera ayudarme a entender porqué no funciona.

Comment: puedes añadir el codigo que queda generado en tu aplicacion? asi con el resultado final podemos ver como ha quedado construido y quizas ver mejor el problema.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El `data-target` de los indicadores y el `href` de las flechas tienen que hacer referencia al `ID` del carrusel.

El `ID` del carrusel es `carouselExampleCaptions`, pero tanto en los indicadores como en las flechas estás usando `carouselExampleIndicators`.

Debería ser:

```
<li data-target="#carouselExampleCaptions" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
<li data-target="#carouselExampleCaptions" data-slide-to="1" class=""></li>
```

```
<a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleCaptions" role="button" data-slide="prev">...</a>
<a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleCaptions" role="button" data-slide="next">...</a>
```

Comment: Muchísimas gracias. Lo tendré en cuenta para el futuro. De verdad te agradezco la ayuda.